# How do we show $\sum \frac{x^n}{1+x^n}$ converges on $x\in [0,1)$?

Tags: calculus, limits, summation

My first thought is to use ratio test. So $\lim \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\lim x\frac{1+x^n}{1+x^{n+1}}=\lim x\frac{\frac{1}{x^{n+1}}+\frac1x}{\frac{1}{x^{n+1}}+1}=1$. So ratio test gives no information. But I think the condition $x\in [0,1)$ is made specifically for ratio or root test. Could someone explain to me how to solve such problem?

Comment: That's odd, when I worked out $\lim(a_{n+1})/a_n)$ I didn't get $1$.

Comment: Hint:  $\lim_{n\to\infty} x^n=$ what, given $0\le x<1$?  In light of that you can easily calculate $\lim (1+x^n)/(1+x^{n+1})$ I think.

Answer (score 6):

If $x\geq 0$ then $1+x^n\geq 1$, hence
$$ 0\leq \frac{x^n}{1+x^n}\leq x^n $$
And $\sum x^n$ converges for all $x\in[0,1)$ because it's a geometric series, hence the original series converges by the comparison test.

Answer (score 4):

By AM-GM inequality: $0 \le \dfrac{x^n}{1+x^n}< \dfrac{x^n}{2\sqrt{x^n}}= \dfrac{1}{2}\left(\sqrt{x}\right)^n$, and this is a geometric series with $a = \sqrt{x} \in [0,1)$ is convergent, and the former series is convergent by comparison test.